# Error when changing Databricks Auto Loader path in directory listing mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I use Databricks (DBR 14.3 LTS) and Auto Loader to run a daily ingestion job that loads all data from a directory structure organized by day in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.

The Databricks documentation says

> In Databricks Runtime 11.3 LTS and above, you can change the directory input path for Auto Loader configured with directory listing mode without having to choose a new checkpoint directory.

However, when I change the directory input path I get the following error:

> Failed to initialize filesystem abfss://abc@def.dfs.core.windows.net/input/20240227: Failure to initialize configuration for storage account def.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key

Here is the code I use:

```py
(
    spark
    .readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "avro")
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", SCHEMA_LOCATION_DIR)
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "rescue")
    .load("abfss://abc@def.dfs.core.windows.net/input/20240228")
    .select("_metadata", "*")
    .writeStream
    .format("delta")
    .option("checkpointLocation", CHECKPOINT_LOCATION_DIR)
    .option("mergeSchema", "true")
    .outputMode("append")
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
    .toTable("catalog.schema.table")
)
```

The location `abc@def.dfs.core.windows.net` exists as an external location in Unity Catalog.

Do you have any idea of what's going on?